# Boot message conflicting device mode

Tags: server, raid

HI I'm running ubuntu server 14.1. There is a nvidia fakeraid array active. The raid is working, however on boot I see these messages (1 of 3 messages):

> Systemd-udevd[599]: conflicting device node
>   '/dev/mapper/nvidia_cbdcebfc1' found, link to '/dev/dm-1' will not be
>   created.

Is there something I haven't configured, I haven't really seen this answered elsewhere but I can see others have asked the same question before?